# Как вставить курсор в нужное место?

Tags: javascript

При клике на кнопку, в блок **(с атрибутом contenteditable)** помещается имя и оборачивается в элемент **b** и надо потом печатать после имени, если кликнуть потом в этот блок, то курсор не выходит за пределы элемента **b** и получается весь напечатанный текст будет тоже жирным, как вывести курсор за этот элемент?

Почему то **selectionStart** н﻿е работает﻿.

```
<p style="
padding: 10px; 
background: white; 
width: 50%;" 

contenteditable="true" class="write-comment"></p>
```

---

```
var formComment = document.querySelector('.write-comment');
var userName﻿Html = document.createElement('b'); 
userNameHtml.innerHTML = userName + ',&nbsp;';

formComment.appendChild(userNameHtml);
formComment.focus();﻿
formComment.selectionStart = formComment.innerHTML.length;
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант остальной текст вынести в отдельный элемент:

```js
var userName="Vovan";
var formComment = document.querySelector('.write-comment');
var userNameHtml = document.createElement('b');
userNameHtml.innerHTML = userName + ',';
var otherText = document.createElement('span');
otherText.innerHTML="&nbsp;";

formComment.appendChild(userNameHtml);
formComment.appendChild(otherText);
formComment.childNodes[1].selectionStart = 0;
formComment.childNodes[1].focus();
```

```html
<p style="
padding: 10px; 
background: white; 
width: 50%;" 

contenteditable="true" class="write-comment"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

В качестве альтернативы:

```js
function go() {
  var formComment = document.querySelector('.write-comment');
  var userNameHtml = document.createElement('b');
  var emptyNode = document.createTextNode(' ');

  userNameHtml.contentEditable = false;
  userNameHtml.innerHTML = "NAME" + ',&nbsp;';

  formComment.appendChild(userNameHtml);
  formComment.appendChild(emptyNode);

  var range = document.createRange();
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  range.setStartAfter(emptyNode);
  range.collapse(false);
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
}
```

```html
<p style="
 padding: 10px; 
 background: white; 
 width: 50%;border:1px solid black;" contenteditable="true" id="write-comment" class="write-comment"></p>
<button onclick="go()">GO</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let button =  document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click',
function(){
  let formComment = document.querySelector('.write-comment');
  let userName = 'Vasia'
  let range  =  document.createRange();
  formComment.focus()
  let selection =  window.getSelection()  
  range.selectNodeContents(formComment);
  let userNameHtml = document.createElement('b');
  let space =  document.createTextNode(' ')
  formComment.insertBefore(space,userNameHtml.nextChild)
  userNameHtml.textContent = userName
  range.insertNode(userNameHtml)
  let newRange  =  document.createRange();
  range.selectNodeContents(formComment)
  range.collapse()
  selection.removeAllRanges()
  selection.addRange(range)
  selection.collapseToEnd();
})
```

```css
.write-comment{

 white-space: pre;

}
```

```html
<p style="
padding: 10px; 
background: white; 
width: 50%; " 

contenteditable="true" class="write-comment"></p>


<button id='button'>click</button>
```